# How to report your status?

Tags: reported-speech

I'm working in IT company and here we have daily standup meetings where people report theirs statuses to the customer. I'm trying to improve my team's reports quality by collecting good sentence starters.

I'd really appreciate any help. So far I have this

Successful:

1. [Today] I was working on [ticket#]
2. [Today] I’ve done next tasks: ticket#,
3. [Today] I fixed next tasks: ticket#
4. [Today] I made some changes to [ticket#]
5. Most of the day I was working on [ticket#]

Issues

1. [Today] I’ve faced issues with [issue description]
2. [Today] some issues has happened with [issue description]

Blockers

1. I’m blocked [in some area] by [situation description]

Comment: This is really no different to Off Topic "Please do my homework for me" questions. Please identify ***one specific*** construction you're concerned about, explaining what you do and don't know about how to use it.

Comment: I'm concerned that English learners in my team use one phrase for all cases: Today I was working on... I'd like to enrich status reports a bit with the phrases, that native speakers would use in this situation.

Comment: I understand perfectly well what you're trying to do. I just don't think the question(s) as presented are really suitable for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to explain. In any industry there can be unique "jargon" which disobeys the rules of English. I worked in IT for 18 years and understand the jargon you refer to. A "ticket" is used in ITIL to describe a logged support call. I believe it is meant to convey the idea that everybody who logs a support request holds a virtual "ticket" entitling them to service. In some stores where there is a counter service they have a literal paper ticket machine on the counter and everybody who walks in takes the next sequentially numbered ticket so that everybody is seen in fair order. But in ITIL the "ticket" is not literal and is often used by those in the industry to describe the actual task assigned to you, so do not expect it to be used the way it would normally be in everyday English.

As a basic rule of thumb, use jargon the same way you would use the word or phrase that it is substituting for. I would say any of the following:

> Today I was working on ticket 19000
>   Today I have *completed* ticket 19000
>   Today I have *resolved* ticket 19000 ("resolved" is the correct ITIL terminology for a completed support ticket)
>   Today I have updated ticket 19000
>   Most of the day I was working on ticket 19000

If you don't refer to your jobs as "tickets", instead use whatever terminology is usual (incident, task, job etc)

> Today I’ve faced issues with [issue description]
>
> Today *there have been some issues with* [issue description]
>
> I’m blocked [in some area] by [situation description]

The first two seem fine, but I wouldn't use the word "blocked" - I would probably say:

> I'm having difficulty with....
>    **OR**
>   Ticket 19000 is *held up* due to...

As I explained already, don't get too hung up on the English language rules when you are working with industry jargon. If your colleagues say it, it is probably correct or at least idiomatic. One ITIL term that always irritated me was "*unresolved*", because in English that means it has never been resolved, but in ITIL it means something that was once marked as resolved but that decision has been overturned. Again, this just proves that the rules of English may not apply here.